# the sum of many polytopes has round shape.?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I generate 1000 polytopes $P_1, \ldots, P_{1000}$ in $\mathbb  R^{n}$, each of them has $m$ vertices that are $m$ rows of an $m\times n$ matrix 
$A_i={\sf rand(m,n)}$. Then I take their sum $P=P_1+\ldots +P_{1000}$. From what I have observed by plotting $P$, it seems that $P$ is nearly round.

Can you prove this fact or can you give an example in which the sum of 1000 polytopes (which has nonempty interior) is really flat.

Comment: Of course there exists examples, just that the probability for that to happen can be low.

Comment: Cuold you please give a complete answer and give a counter example.

Comment: Apply a transformation $D=\operatorname{diag}\,[\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{\text{$k$ times}},\underbrace{\epsilon,\epsilon,\dots,\epsilon}_{\text{$n-k$ times}}]$ to all the $P_i$. Then their sum will also be transformed by $D$. If it was nearly round before like an $n$-dimensional ball, it will become really flat like a $k$-dimensional disk.

Comment: @Rahul: The resulting polytope should have non-interior in R^n.

Comment: What is a non-interior?

Comment: If you want the polytope to not have an interior, set $\epsilon=0$. If you want it to have a *nonempty* interior, keep $0<\epsilon\ll 1$.

Comment: @Rahul: I am sorry, it should be with nonempty interior.